# gthread.h size of array is negative

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, gstreamer

I have following configuration in my .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/vickey/ossbuild-read-only/Shared/Build/Linux/x86/include/glib-2.0/
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-0.10
LIBS            += -L/usr/lib `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`
LIBS        += -L. -L/usr/lib -lphonon -lcurl -ltag -fopenmp -lsayonara_gstreamer
```

When I try to build the project I get the following error

```
/home/vickey/src/player/../../../../ossbuild-read-only/Shared/Build/Linux/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:-1: In function 'gboolean g_once_init_enter(volatile gsize*)':

/home/vickey/src/player/../../../../ossbuild-read-only/Shared/Build/Linux/x86/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:348: error: size of array is negative
```

Double clicking on error takes me to gthread.h file with below lines pointed

```
g_once_init_enter (volatile gsize *value_location)
{
  if G_LIKELY ((gpointer) g_atomic_pointer_get (value_location) != NULL)
    return FALSE;
  else
    return g_once_init_enter_impl (value_location);
}
```

what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I bet `g_atomic_pointer_get` misuses `__builtin_constant_p`, assuming a zero return *guarantees* it's not a built-in constant.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error compiling ancient glib and pango for a 64-bit platform.

Here's how `g_atomic_pointer_get` source looks in that version:

```
# define g_atomic_pointer_get(atomic) \
 ((void) sizeof (gchar [sizeof (*(atomic)) == sizeof (gpointer) ? 1 : -1]), \
  (g_atomic_pointer_get) ((volatile gpointer G_GNUC_MAY_ALIAS *) (volatile void *) (atomic)))
```

So, here `atomic` is `gsize`, which must have the same `sizeof` as `gpointer`, i.e. `void*`.

It helped me to redefine `gsize` and `gssize` to be 8-byte on 64bit architecture in `glibconfig.h`.

Also update `GLIB_SIZEOF_VOID_P`, `GLIB_SIZEOF_LONG` and `GLIB_SIZEOF_SIZE_T`.